# Invocation of get method instead of set in Proxy object

Tags: javascript, typescript, proxy

Coders! I began to research JavaScript Proxy objects and faced some strange behaviour of one.
I'm trying to push a number to proxied array, but, unexpectedly for me, `get` method invoked, **if it exists**! However, if I delete `get` method in `arrayHandler`, `set` is invoked as expected, and number is pushed. Why is it possible?

```
class SomeClass {
    public readonly name: String;
    public originalData: Array<number> = [];

    private arrayHandler = {
        set(
            target: Array<number>,
            prop: number,
            val: any,
            reciever: any
        ): boolean {
            console.log("PROXY HANDLER SET");
            target[prop] = val;
            return true;
        },
        get(target: Array<number>, prop: number): void {
            console.log("PROXY HANDLER GET");
        },
    };
    public proxyToArray: any = new Proxy(this.originalData, this.arrayHandler);

    constructor(name: String) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

let item = new SomeClass("item-1");
item.proxyToArray.push(1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the target in the getter:

```
class SomeClass {
    public readonly name: String;
    public originalData: Array<number> = [];

    private arrayHandler = {
        set(
            target: Array<number>,
            prop: number,
            val: any,
            reciever: any
        ): boolean {
            console.log("PROXY HANDLER SET");
            target[prop] = val;
            return true;
        },
        get(target: Array<number>, prop: number): any {
            console.log("PROXY HANDLER GET");
            return target[prop];
        },
    };
    public proxyToArray: any = new Proxy(this.originalData, this.arrayHandler);

    constructor(name: String) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

let item = new SomeClass("item-1");
item.proxyToArray.push(1);
```

Comment: Anyway, why method GET is invoked along with SET on proxy object, when I call push()? It's not obvious for me, since I expect only SET method;